Should I be concerned about a very minor leak from water heater, when pilot was out?
Gas water heater... I'd estimate around '07 installation.
Through a series of (rather comical and moronic) Three-Stooges-esque events, the gas to the water heater got shut off Friday afternoon. It was off for just a few minutes, then turned back on.
Not a whole lot of hot water use over the weekend and when I went to shower this morning.. no hot water. This is when it occurred to me if the gas was shut off, even for a couple minutes, the pilot light probably went out.. and sure enough it did.
Relit the pilot without an issue.
When relighting the pilot I noticed a very minute amount of water on the heater's pedestal (it sits 2-2.5ft above ground on a metal platform). It was just enough water to cause a "shine" which I noticed and then make me touch it to verify it wasn't my eyes playing tricks. It's literally like 0.0625" of water with about a 4" circumference - far more "wet spot" than puddle.
Prior to this mishap the water heater has been performing, without any leaks or issues, for some time.
Should I be concerned about this minor leak which occurred when the pilot light was out?
Or.. is this perhaps some "seepage" that might be expected if the heater is cold for a couple days?

Just a general follow up... the wet spot dried and hasn't reappeared. It does appear that it was merely condensation.

The tank's age is getting into the time for it to start leaking, but this sounds more like a beer glass condensation wetness than a leak.
Warmer air with some moisture in it, touches a cooler surface.
It would be good to keep a closer eye on it from now on.  Hot water tank leaks can lead to flooding.  A moisture/water type alarm nearby could be handy.

Thanks, yes. This could feasibly be chalked up to a condensation collection due to how minor it is. Which Is why I wasn't certain if it was a problem or not. I will be keeping an eye on it to make sure nothing seems to get worse. I realize it's aging and nearly 20yrs is an exceptionally  good run. It is located in a garage. So, thankfully if it were to, knock-wood, flood. There wouldn't be any major damage other than replacement costs.

@Scott   If it is condensation, it should go away now that the tank is warm/working again.  If it does not dry up, then it is time for replacement thoughts.

Thanks. Will watch it. Thanks again.

Yes, wipe it up and monitor it.  But be prepared (financially and mentally) to have to replace it.
